# formset_factory with forms with different initial data

Tags: django, forms, django-views, django-forms

I am writing a view that uses POST data to display multiple forms with differing prefilled FK's

I have a ModelForm in forms.py

```
class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Survey
```

who's model looks like this...

```
class Survey(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    surveyset = models.ForeignKey(SurveySet)

    cei_0  = models.BooleanField()
    cei_1  = models.BooleanField()
```

**My view looks kind of like this so far**

```
# ... after building a list from POST we essentially have:
list_of_studentids = [1,3,2,6,7,45]

students = []
for i in list_of_student_ids:
    students.append(Student.objects.filter(id=i))

SurveyFormSet = formset_factory(SurveyForm, extra=6)

formset = SurveyFormSet(initial=[
    {'surveyset': SurveySet.create(),
    'student': ?????,}
])
```

How do I return a bunch of forms with different student FK's and the same surveyset FK?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an [instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) attribute to the form:

```
prefilled_survey = Survey(student=student_instance, surveyset=surveyset_instance)
form = SurveyForm(request.POST or None, instance=prefilled_survey)
```

Comment: I need multiple forms with different instances.